# Get user's IP address in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I get the IP address of user's computer in TypeScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Assuming this JavaScript/TypeScript runs inside the browser:*

Neither JavaScript nor TypeScript will allow this directly: for all you know, the user might have gone offline, he's behind a NAT, etc.

Make an AJAX request to your server and have the backend determine the IP.